# Having trouble with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I want to solve the following equation for $a$:

$$\frac{3a}{12} - \frac{4a + 8} { 12} = 9
$$
What should my first steps be?

If I should cross multiply the two fractions on the LHS, but, if I do one thing to one side, shouldn't I also do it to the other side? Why doesnt this rule apply here, if it doesn't?

I hate fractions.. is this hard??

Comment: Multiply all terms by $12$ (the common denominator of the lhs), expand and simplify. Fractions are simple and you will enjoy them very soon.

Answer (score 2):

$$\require{cancel}$$

The first step is to subtract the quotients and simplify:

$$\frac{3a}{12}-\frac{(4a+8)}{12}=9\iff \frac{3a-(4a+8)}{12}=9\iff \frac{-a-8}{12}=9$$
Now we have
$$\frac{-a-8}{12}=9\iff \cancel{\color{red}{12}}\times\frac{-a-8}{\cancel{12}}=\color{red}{12}\times9=108\iff a=-8-108=-116$$

Answer (score 1):

First, add the fractions:

$$\dfrac{3a}{12} - \dfrac{(4a+8)}{12}= 9 \iff  = \dfrac{3a-(4a+8)}{12} = \dfrac{-a - 8}{12} = \dfrac{-(a + 8)}{12} = 9$$

Now multiply both sides of the equation by $-12$:

$$\require{cancel} -(\cancel{12})\cdot\dfrac{-(a + 8)}{\cancel{12}} = -(12)\cdot 9$$ Can you take it from here?